# SelectRaw in blade template to create dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

A database table has two fields first_name and last_name.
If I want to fill a dropdown box i can use this code:

```
{!! Form::select('driver_id',  App\Driver::pluck('first_name','id'), null, ['class' => 'form-control'])  !!}
```

But if I want concat two fileds i should use a SelectRow on my model:

```
{!! Form::select('driver_id',  App\Driver::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS full_name, id"))->pluck('full_name','id'), null, ['class' => 'form-control'])  !!}
```

But this solution does not works and this is what i get:

```
<select class="form-control" name="driver_id">
<option value="">Autista...</option>
<option value="11"> </option>
<option value="12"> </option>
<option value="13"> </option>
.....
</select>
```

That is.... the select does not get "full_name" filed but get the "id" field.
How to solve ?

Comment: You can make a concat array into your controller and then pass it to select tag in your view blade

Comment: Sure. But how to have this elegant solution working ?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your own question instead of inside the question itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
{{ Form::select('driver_id',  App\Driver::select(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS full_name, id"))->lists('full_name','id'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: lists function is not available from laravel 5.3 version.

Comment: Thank you. But the collection method ->lists() is deprecated.

>The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try This in your blade file:

```
App\Driver::select(
        DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS full_name"),'id')
        ->pluck('full_name', 'id');
```

Comment: No. The problem is the **alias field name** anyway. Pluck function cannot find the field "full_name". 
See also [laravel camel_case()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-camel-case) for more info.

Comment: OK ..fine..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

The problem is the **underscore** character in the alias field name "**full_name**".

This code works fine:

```
App\Driver::selectRaw("CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as fullname ,id")->pluck("fullname", "id")
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: OK fine...Thanks to You